# Usage of all available threads for OMP inside Master MPI only part - hybrid parallel programming

Tags: multithreading, mpi, openmp, intel-mpi, ms-mpi

Is it possible to use all available threads for OMP on a region where only master MPI is active?. I mean something like this:

```
         START 
           |
 MPI-I --------- MPI-II
(master)
   |               |
omp1-omp2       -skip-         REGION1 
omp3-omp4       -skip-
   |               |
omp1-omp2      omp3-omp4       REGION2
   |               |
   -----------------
          | 
         END
```

Where nr. total threads available*** is 4 (2 are used for mpi, 4 used by MPI1 -master- on Region1, and 2 used by each MPI on Region2).

It looks like this is only working on Windows*, not on Linux**. On Linux, omp_get_num_procs() seems to detect that threads are being used by other mpi procs. and retrieves a different number -lower- than that Windows does (which gives all available*** ones, irrespective whether they are currently occupied by other mpi active procs.)

On Linux even using explicitly the following clause !$OMP &num_threads(Max_OMP_usage), with Max_OMP_usage equal to the total number of threads available***, within the OMP DO construct has no effect.

*Windows:   Intel ifort, MSMPI

**Linux: Intel ifort, MPI OneApi2021.

***By total nr. of threads available I mean the ones "lscpu" retrieves for example, this is, the ones present physically (and not the one omp_get_num_procs() may retrieve).

Comment: The MPI implementation typically assign non overlapping core sets to each MPI task. So if at some point in time a task requires more, you would have to direct your MPI implementation **not** to do any process binding.

Comment: Yes, using I_MPI_PIN=0 it works! Thanks a lot!.

Comment: You do realize that you're using the fact that your MPI processes are on the same processor chip or at least the same node? That is not necessarily the case: MPI was designed for workstation networks and clusters where the MPI processes could only communicate through a network cable.

Comment: Yes, yes Master mpi only executes Region1 in omp parallel. Any other mpi process -other than the master- irrespective to the node where it is located (same node -chip- than master mpi or not) will simply skip it. Yes, I do realize that those omp threads (omp lives inside a single node) are occupied by mpi processes but at that point they are not making any work as they skip that part and meet master mpi only at Region2

Answer (score 0):

@Gilles Gouaillardet & @Costagol

Yes, you are correct. We need to set I_MPI_PIN=0 in order to stop process binding & thus only the master can use all the OMP threads.

You can also find the links below for the Interoperability with OpenMP and Environment Variables for Process Pinning:

https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/mpi-developer-reference-linux/top/environment-variable-reference/process-pinning/interoperability-with-openmp-api.html

https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/mpi-developer-reference-linux/top/environment-variable-reference/process-pinning/environment-variables-for-process-pinning.html